# Service Uses Increasingly More Memory

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service on the app which needs to run indefinitely - even when app is closed. It's going to ping a network source, if a state changes then the service must trigger a notification. The loop triggering the pings in the service is user chosen, with the smallest value of 5000ms (5 Seconds). I have the pings on a separate thread (off the UI thread) with calls to a handler thread to post toasts (temporarily while programming) to the UI thread.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast successMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    successMessage.show();

    //sendToastOnUIThread(1000);

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(GLOBAL_PING_TIMER);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sendToastOnUIThread();
                //Code for pings here...


            }

        }
    }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Above you can see my onStartCommand from the service - when testing this, I only used the code above and left out my code to ping the network source etc.

Incase you wonder whats in 'sendToastOnUIThread();'

```
public void sendToastOnUIThread(){

    Handler h = new Handler(AutoPingServerService.this.getMainLooper());

    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(AutoPingServerService.this,"Servers Pinged",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

So when this service is running, I get the toasts every 5 seconds, but the service memory just keeps stacking up (seems to cap at 8.5mb) but starts off around 1mb and just builds up around 0.1mb per loop. Am I making too many threads somehow? There should only be the UI thread, the new thread to handle the pings and the handler thread to post toasts when I need them (this will be replaces with notifications once it works)

Open to ideas - fairly new to android development, I wouldn't be surprised if i'm using all the wrong thread types. Possibly this is normal?

EDIT: Spelling.

Comment: My initial thought is the garbage collector just isn't triggering yet so it's not collecting your object references that's being created in each loop. If that's the case then you should see a drop after a certain amount of time. Either way you may want to look in to `IntentService`.

Comment: @DeeV The only reason I stayed away from IntentService was because (from what I read) the Service class is easier to keep persistent, and more designed for actual calculations where a IntentService was for services  for an intent and not when the application is closed, also aren't IntentService only for small jobs? this job needs to run 24/7.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but I don't think you want to create a new handler every time you send a toast on the UI thread. Incidentally, what happens if you explicitly call System.gc() at some point?

Comment: They're intended for small jobs that need to run even when the user closes the application (IntentService actually extends from Service). I don't know how complex your calculations are, but if they only last a few milliseconds every five seconds then it may be the better choice (also a Service can't run 24/7 as the system may kill it at any time to clear resources for more important apps).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Sadly this does nothing - memory continue to rise. Highest reached so far was 9mb after 40Mins (So it must be automatically clearing  the older memory?)

Comment: @Deev I did not know it extended the Service class. Yes my calculations take a brief moment. They ping a http:// source and wait a response code - then it uses this to update a database (updating the new response code). Okay, I'll try implement this with a IntentService - but what benefits will this have over just Service?

Comment: It's just simpler, more compact, and handles all the threading for you. `IntentService#onHandleIntent()` does everything off-thread already so you don't have to worry about it. It also executes sequentially so if your last ping (for some reason) took 8 seconds, then your next one will wait until the last one is finished before starting.

Comment: @Deev Okay, nearly done migrating all the code - will let you know if I still have memory problems once I've ran it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay update for anyone curious:

The memory does get wiped after a while (pweh) as you'll reach a terminal capacity. Not sure if this is ideal but hey - I'm not going to sell it for millions, if the app crashes, I'll update this post. Don't fix what's not broken eh?

Anyway - @Deev kindly said I should move to an IntentService, I did not. I possibly will in the future, but this method works (Although it does look simpler to use a IntentService).